# python server with images

Tags: python, html

I'm running an python server that loads a login page. All the html pages will load (they're in the same folder as the html page that's being hosted, so are the images), but the images that are in the same folder as the html don't load.Anybody know what's wrong with the image loading ? Thanks. Here's the code:

```
#/usr/bin/python
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
from os import curdir, sep

PORT_NUMBER = 8080

#This class will handles any incoming request from
#the browser 
class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    #Handler for the GET requests
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path=="/":
            self.path="login.html"

        try:
            #Check the file extension required and
            #set the right mime type

            sendReply = False
            if self.path.endswith(".html"):
                mimetype='text/html'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".jpg"):
                mimetype='image/jpg'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".gif"):
                mimetype='image/gif'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".js"):
                mimetype='application/javascript'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".css"):
                mimetype='text/css'
                sendReply = True

            if sendReply == True:
                #Open the static file requested and send it
                f = open(curdir + sep + self.path) 
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type',mimetype)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(f.read())
                f.close()
            return


        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)

try:
    #Create a web server and define the handler to manage the
    #incoming request
    server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
    print 'Started httpserver on port ' , PORT_NUMBER

    #Wait forever for incoming htto requests
    server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print '^C received, shutting down the web server'
    server.socket.close()
```

Comment: Maybe the web server is not configured to route that file extension to your Python handler?

Comment: Oh, like the images could be png's? Yeah let me check on that

Comment: I fixed the png problem thanks. One of the input fields doesn't load, but I'll have to look into that. Not sure what could be causing that.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following code for jpg/png files accordingly

```
if self.path.endswith(".jpg"):
                            f = open(applicationPath + '/' + self.path, 'rb')
                            self.send_response(200)
                            self.send_header('Content-type',        'image/png')
                            self.end_headers()
                            self.wfile.write(f.read())
                            f.close()
                            return
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add mode='rb' to f = open(curdir + sep + self.path) because you are reading a binary file.